# Error in importing data into neo4j via csv

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j.
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong?, please help.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:\Users\Chandra Harsha\Downloads\neo4j_module_datasets\test.csv" as line
    MERGE (n:Node{name:line.Source})
    MERGE (m:Node{name:line.Target})
    MERGE (n)-[:TO{distance:line.dist}]->(m)
```

Error message:
Invalid input 's': expected four hexadecimal digits specifying a unicode character (line 1, column 41 (offset: 40))
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:\Users\Chandra Harsha\Downloads\neo4j_module_datasets\test.csv" as line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems here.

The immediate error is that the backslashes in the path are being seen as escape characters rather than folder separators - you either have to escape the backslashes (by just doubling them up) or use forward-slashes instead. For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:\\Users\\Chandra Harsha\\Downloads\\neo4j_module_datasets\\test.csv" as line
    MERGE (n:Node{name:line.Source})
    MERGE (m:Node{name:line.Target})
    MERGE (n)-[:TO{distance:line.dist}]->(m)
```

**However** - Neo4j doesn't allow you to load files from arbitrary places on the filesystem anyway as a security precaution. Instead, you should move the file you want to import into the `import` folder under your database. If you're using Neo4j Desktop, you can find this by selecting your database project and clicking the little down-arrow icon on 'Open Folder', choosing 'Import' from the list.

[image]

Drop the CSV in there, then just use its filename in your file space. So for example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" as line
    MERGE (n:Node{name:line.Source})
    MERGE (m:Node{name:line.Target})
    MERGE (n)-[:TO{distance:line.dist}]->(m)
```

You can still use folders under the `import` directory - anything starting `file:///` will be resolved relative to that import folder, so things like the following are also fine:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///neo4j_module_datasets/test.csv" as line
    MERGE (n:Node{name:line.Source})
    MERGE (m:Node{name:line.Target})
    MERGE (n)-[:TO{distance:line.dist}]->(m)
```